# Need to a have a post deployment task on the pod of same deployment

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-pod

I am writing ansible scripts for deploying services using Kubernetes, I am stuck with a step that is for the post-deployment process:

I have deployed a service having "**replicas: 3**", and all the replicas are up and running now my problem is to I have to do a migration for which I have to get into the container and run a script already present there.

I can do it manually by getting into the container individually and then run the script but this will again require manual intervention.

What I want to achieve is once the deployment is done and all the replicas are up and running I want to run the scripts by getting into the containers and all these steps should be performed by ansible script and no manual effort required.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vasili Angapov is right - **k8s_exec** module is probably the best solution in this case but I would like to add some useful notes.

---

To use **k8s_exec** we need to know the exact `Pod` name (we need to pass it as `pod` parameter in ansible task). As you wrote, I assume that your `Pods` are managed by `Deployment`, so every `Pod` has random string in its name added by `ReplicaSet`. Therefore, you have to find the full names of the `Pods` somehow.
I've created simple playbook to illustrate how we can find `Pod` names for all `Pods` with label: `app=web` and then run sample `touch file123456789` command on these `Pods`.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  collections:
    - community.kubernetes

  tasks:     
    - name: "Search for all Pods labelled app=web"
      k8s_info:
        kind: Pod
        label_selectors:
          - app = web
      register: pod_names

    - name: "Get Pod names"
      set_fact:
        pod_names: "{{ pod_names | json_query('resources[*].metadata.name') }}"

    - name: "Run command on every Pod labelled app=web"
      k8s_exec:
        namespace: default
        pod: "{{ item }}"
        command: touch file123456789
      with_items: "{{ pod_names }}"
```

**NOTE:** Instead of `k8s_exec` module you can use `command` module as well.
In our example instead of `k8s_exec` task we can have:

```
- name: "Run command on every Pod labelled app=web"
  command: >
    kubectl exec "{{ item }}" -n default -- touch file123456789
  with_items: "{{ pod_names }}"
```

Comment: @matt_i, thanks for the solution as this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Anuj Kishor  Good to hear that. Consider accepting the answer as it solved your issue. That way it would be more clear and visible for the rest of the community.

Comment: @matt_i sure the solution is great, just the running commands under the pod is throwing error, i believe it is my environment issue, do you know the reason for the error:

```failed: [localhost] (item=afroaves-app-5dcf4bbfd9-jwdjg) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "afroaves-app-5dcf4bbfd9-jwdjg", "msg": "Failed to execute on pod afroaves-app-5dcf4bbfd9-jwdjg due to : (0)\nReason: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 403\n"}```

I am able to run it via kubectl command

Comment: @Anuj Kishor Your error could be caused by how you are connecting to the cluster. Instead of `k8s_exec` module you can use `command` module (`command` module should't cause such errors). I updated my answer to be more general.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [k8s_exec](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_exec_module.html) module.

```
- name: Check RC status of command executed
  community.kubernetes.k8s_exec:
    namespace: myproject
    pod: busybox-test
    command: cmd_with_non_zero_exit_code
  register: command_status
  ignore_errors: True

- name: Check last command status
  debug:
    msg: "cmd failed"
  when: command_status.return_code != 0
```